# Add Python Script as a file to AWS SSM Document (YAML)

Tags: python, terraform, aws-ssm

I'm trying to write a script for a SystemsManager Automation document and would like to keep the Python code in a seperate file so it's easy to invoke on my local machine. For complex scripts they can also be tested using a tool such as unittest.

Example YAML syntax from my SSM Automation:

```yaml
mainSteps:
  - name: RunTestScript
    action: aws:executeScript
    inputs:
      Runtime: python3.8
      Handler: handler
      InputPayload:
        Action: "Create" # This is just a random payload for now I'm only testing
      Script: |-
        "${script}" # My script should be injected here :)
```

Note: Yes, I've written the script directly in YAML and it works fine. But I'd like to achieve something similar to:

```rust
locals {
  script = file("${path.module}/automations/test.py")
}

resource "aws_ssm_document" "aws_test_script" {
  name            = "test-script"
  document_format = "YAML"
  document_type   = "Automation"
  content = templatefile("${path.module}/automations/test.yaml", {
    ssm_automation_assume_role = aws_iam_role.ssm_automation.arn
    script                     = local.script
  })
}
```

My console shows that yes the file is being read correctly.

```
Terraform plan...:
          +         "def handler(event, context):
          +     print(event)
          +     import boto3
          +     iam = boto3.client('iam')
          +     response = iam.get_role(
          +         RoleName='test-role'
          +     )
          +     print(response)"
```

Notice how the indentation is broken? My `.py` file has the correct indentation.

I suspect one of the terraform functions or YAML operators I'm using it breaking the indentation - which is very important for a language such as Python.

If I go ahead and Terraform apply I receive:

`Error: Error updating SSM document: InvalidDocumentContent: YAML not well-formed. at Line: 30, Column: 1`

I tried changing the last line in my YAML to be `Script: "${script}"` and I can Terraform Plan and Apply fine, but the Python script is on a single line and fails when executing the automation in AWS.

I've also tried using `indent(4, local.script)` without success.

Keen to hear/see what ideas and solutions you may have.

Thanks

Comment: Is this a `\t` versus `\s` issue?

Comment: Thanks @MattSchuchard, not too sure, my editor uses 4 spaces so I could try a tab and compare results hmmmm it's very hard to find examples of people doing this but I'm just not too keen to write python in yaml compared to using a .py file

Answer (score 1):

I noticed my plan output had `"`'s around the code. So I tried a multiline string in Python `"""` and it continued to fail. Bearing in mind I assumed SSM was smart enough to strip quotes if it doesn't want them.

Anyway, the mistake was adding quotes around the template variable:

```
# Mistake
      Script: |-
        "${script}" # My script should be injected here :)
```

Solution

```
      Script: |-
        ${script}
```

After that I decided okay now that it works, can I remove the `indent()` method I'm using and I got the YAML not well-formed error back.

So using:

```rust
locals {
  script = indent(8, file("${path.module}/automations/test.py"))
}

resource "aws_ssm_document" "test_script" {
  name            = "test-script"
  document_format = "YAML"
  document_type   = "Automation"
  content = templatefile("${path.module}/automations/test.yaml", {
    ssm_automation_assume_role = aws_iam_role.ssm_automation.arn
    script                     = local.script
  })
}
```

Works great with:

```
mainSteps:
  - name: RunDMSRolesScript
    action: aws:executeScript
    inputs:
      Runtime: python3.8
      Handler: handler
      InputPayload:
        Action: "create"
      Script: |-
        ${script}
```

If it helps anyone, this is what my SSM Script looks like in the AWS UI when it runs without errors. Formatted correctly and AWS seems to append `"` around it but turned into `"\"` when I provided quotes in my YAML template which would've broken the script as it's now a **string literal**.

```
"def handler(event, context):
    print(event)
    import boto3

    iam = boto3.client('iam')
    response = iam.get_role(
        RoleName='test-role'
    )
    print(response)"
```

That's one way to lose 3 hours!